# Did Steve Jobs compare Apple's market share with BMW, Mercedes-Benz's and Porsche?

Tags: quotes, apple-inc, steve-jobs

From The Register: [Apple CEO Cook: 'We're not in the junk business'](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/09/19/apple_ceo_cook_were_not_in_the_junk_business/)

> Steve Jobs reprised nearly that exact argument in a 2004 interview.
>   "Apple's market share is bigger than BMW's or Mercedes's or Porsche's
>   in the automotive market," he said at the time. "What's wrong with
>   being BMW or Mercedes?"

Wikiquote currently lacks a [source for it](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk:Steve_Jobs#Unsourced), and [Quote Investigator](http://quoteinvestigator.com/category/steve-jobs/) hasn't investigated that quote.

Did Jobs compare Apple's market share with these car companies?

Comment: I don't see the importance of this. It's something entirely plausible for Steve Jobs to have said, and whether he said it or not is pretty irrelevant. His business strategy demonstrated the approach.

Comment: But since I have a few minutes to spare and Google: http://www.macworld.com/article/1029181/themacturns20jobs.html